# Json schema 4 based models with Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, jsonschema

Are there any libraries that would make Doctrine PHP object relational models straight from json schema version 4? If not, is there any sense to implement one and how would you do it? Im thinking possibility to use same schema  both for client side form creation and validation as well as server side storage  and field validation.

PHP JSON Schema v.4 based validation: https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema
JSON to YAML conversion: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/usage

Comment: Interesting.  First time I heard of json schema.  Does not seem like it would that hard to write a converter to both doctrine 2 as well as the symfony 2 validate component.